# Fuelux, how to fix the width of a repeater column

Tags: html, css, fuelux

Is it possible to fix the width of a specific `Fuel UX` repeater column?

I'm trying to do this using the `css-nth` selector like this:

```
.table thead tr th:nth-of-type(8),
.table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(8) {
    background: red;
    width:10px;
    max-width:10px;
}
```

The code above is correct in part, as the background of the 8th column is red, but just on the `<TD>` and not on the `<TH>`, and anyway the width doesn't change.

Any idea on how I can  set a fixed width column? thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT**

I solved this in another way, just adding a container div with a `min-width`, so that the column where the div is stretches to fit the div width and actually it stretches all the column.

Is not the right way, but at least it works as i think that the column size is setted using JS and thats why it did work with just css properties.

thanks anyway!

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: is not that easy, as the table as been generated using javascript and the data is loaded from another ajax request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `list_columnSizing: false` option?

For more info visit: http://getfuelux.com/extensions.html#bundled-extensions-list

Answer (score 0):

try with this

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/1w3aqqn8/)

```
.table tr th:nth-child(8),
.table tr td:nth-child(8) {
    background: red;
    width:10px;
    max-width:10px;
}
```